# Issue in zoom out and in from iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, pinchzoom, uipinchgesturerecognizer, cgaffinetransformscale

I have to tried zoom out and zoom in function in iPad, its working fine, but the zoom clarity is not good, I didn't know that, so how to make this? please help me.

Thanks in Advance

```
// This method will handle the PINCH / ZOOM gesture 
- (void)pinchZoom:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

        if (!zoomActive) {
            zoomActive = YES;

            UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panMove:)];
            [panGesture setMaximumNumberOfTouches:2];
            [panGesture setDelegate:self];
            [self addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
            [panGesture release];

        }

        [gestureRecognizer view].transform = CGAffineTransformScale([[gestureRecognizer view] transform], [gestureRecognizer scale], [gestureRecognizer scale]);

        [delegate leavesView:self zoomingCurrentView:[gestureRecognizer scale]];            

        [gestureRecognizer setScale:1];


    }
}
```